# Помогите разобраться с циклом (Iterator) для List

Tags: java, list, arraylist, итераторы

У меня есть ArrayList  box (коробка с фигурами). Мне нужно реализовать метод, который вытаскивает из коробки все круглые фигуры. Вроде бы всё делаю правильно, но записывает почему-то только одну фигуру. Что не так?

Мой класс Box:

```
public class Box {
    private List<Figure> box = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean addFigure(Figure figure) {
        if (box.contains(figure)) {
            return false;
        }
        box.add(figure);
        return true;
    }

public List<Figure> getAllCircles() {
        List<Figure> circles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListIterator<Figure> iterator = box.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            if (iterator.next() instanceof Circle) {
                circles.add(iterator.next());
            }
        }
        return circles;
    }
}
```

Мой класс Main:

```
  public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();

        PaperCircle paperCircle = new PaperCircle(5);
        PaperCircle paperCircle1 = new PaperCircle(9);

        System.out.println(box.addFigure(paperCircle));
        System.out.println(box.addFigure(paperCircle1));

        for (Iterator<Figure> a = box.getAllCircles().listIterator(); a.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println(a.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
true
true
PaperCircle: radius = 9.0, Color: null
```

***Почему теряется мой круг с радиусом 5.0 ?***

Comment: В методе `getAllCircles()` вы вначале продвигаете указатель итератора с помощью `next()`, проверяете круг, а потом еще раз продвигаете указатель и в итоге пропускает только что считанный элемент. `next()` передвигает текущий указатель!!!

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець а как обратиться к текущей позиции итератора? просто iterator? без .next()?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець можно решить таким образом? это корректно? 
Figure a = iterator.next();
            if (a instanceof Circle) {
                circles.add(a);
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
if (iterator.next() instanceof Circle) {
  circles.add(iterator.next());
}
```

использовать

```
Figure figure = iterator.next();
if (figure instanceof Circle) {
  circles.add(figure);
}
```

или отказаться от итератора вообще, т.к. тут он вовсе не нужен

вместо

```
for (ListIterator<Figure> iterator = box.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    if (iterator.next() instanceof Circle) {
        circles.add(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

использовать

```
for (Figure figure : circles) {
  if (figure instanceof Circle) {
    circles.add(figure);
  }
}
```

Comment: не могли бы Вы провести легкий ликбез по поводу необходимости использования итератора? Нам просто прептдаватель сказал, что List необходисо обходить итератором, т.к. из-за обычного for/for each могут возникать разного рода проблемы

Comment: Одна из таких проблем ComodificationException, когда в процессе обхода добавляются или удаляются элементы листа. Итератор выкинет исключение, а цикл проглотит и будете долго искать ошибку...

Comment: если внутри цикла не изменять коллекцию, по которой работает for/foreach, то никаких проблем быть не может

Comment: От коллекции получаем итератор, hasNext() показывает факт наличия следующего элемента (обычно используется как условие продолжения цикла), next() возвращает этот следующий элемент, если вызвать next() без проверки то получите ошибку, если нет следующего элемента... Проще всего посмотреть документацию, там все четко написано, перейти к исходникам итератора можно прямо из среды (прямо на имени класса Iterator, так чтобы был import его в коде, выполнить ctrl+click, как правило это дефолтная комбинация для перехода к декларациям, или можно в хоткеях среды поискать по словам Navigation Declaration.